# Spring boot: load resources like application.properties is loaded

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Spring boot searches for `application.properties` in different locations:
in classpath, in current folder, in /config folder and so on.

Is there a simple way to load any resource the same way?

For example, I want to load files:

- a.txt
- b.xml
- c.properties

and parse them by myself, not like property files.

Is there a simple way to ask spring boot to find them like it searches for application.properties in different locations?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You should check out [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  It walks through the basics of what makes a good question.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that no there is not a way to ask Spring Boot to this.  However you can review all of their code.   If you look in their ConfigFileApplicationListener class you can see how they have DEFAULT_SEARCH_LOCATIONS defined as the list of places to look for config files and they store this in a Set.  Then they use a ResourceLoader to loop through and check if a desired resource exists at each location.  If you review their code and their [resource documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html) I believe you could build your own service to get a file from a possible list of locations.

Answer (score 0):

`PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` used to load properties on startup and you can access its properties just like application.properties

```java
@Bean
public PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer loadResources() {
    var resourceConfigurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    resourceConfigurer.setLocations(
        new ClassPathResource("file1"),
        new ClassPathResource("file2"),
        new ClassPathResource("file3"));
    resourceConfigurer.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(false);
    resourceConfigurer.setIgnoreResourceNotFound(false);
    return resourceConfigurer;
}
```

**Note:** application.properties are loaded after files registered by `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`